# react-native deploy to android device error 3 activity class does not exist

Tags: java, android, react-native

My app works fine on my simulator so now I am trying to put it on my phone.  When I try install I get the following message

```
...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 15.578 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: http://gradle.org/docs/2.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Starting the app (/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb shell am start -n com.ethicalfishing/.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.ethicalfishing/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.ethicalfishing/com.ethicalfishing.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

I understand this error has been spoken about relating to non-react-native apps, however the solutions given were either not relevant or not helpful (or I didn't understand them)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061034/how-to-generate-androidmanifest-xml-from-a-react-native-app-created-with-react-n location of AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. I found that build.gradle's applicationId and `AndroidManifest.xml` package were different.

build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.yourapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
```

That was the problem in my case.

Comment: Where is the `build.gradle` and `AndroidManifest.xml` files located at?

Comment: @ArchNoob `build.gradle`- ${projectFolder}\android\app.
`AndroidManifest.xml`- ${projectFolder}\android\app\src\main