# how to generate AndroidManifest.xml from a react-native app created with react-native init

Tags: android, reactjs, native, auth0

I used react-native init to create my react application. I'm trying to tie in auth0 and auth0 documentation is saying I need something from the androidManafest.xml. The problem is that the react-native init didn't create "android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml " during the process. How does this get created and tie into my react-native app?

Answer (score 44):

I am doing the same thing and had to hunt around for it, but after I did a `react-native run-android` I found that very file in the following folder: `android` > `app` > `src` > `main`.

[image]

Comment: Also the part you want for Auth0 is here: `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="HERE"`

Comment: The original question explicitly says that the can't find the file "android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml". Telling them the path - the exact path they specifically said they can't find - is not helpful.

Comment: @Benubird based on the fact that 4 people found it helpful, by definition, it is not useless. Also you could stand to be more respectful on this platform. Plus, if you read what I wrote, I mentioned that I ran a command before I found the file. Please be more civil, thanks.

Comment: I ran `react-native run-android`, but where is this android directory? I'm not seeing it anywhere in my project.

Comment: @CharlieStanard the android directory is: `src/android` -- top level in your project

Answer (score 6):

If you are in an Expo In **managed workflow** you will not see the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Since you don’t have access to changing the `xml` file in an Expo managed project, the `app.json` / `app.config.js` file let’s you make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 3):

`AndroidManifest.xml` exists only in the **bare workflow** (`Expo`).
To get an access to these files in **bare workflow** files you need to run `expo eject`. Assuming you are on the **managed workflow**.

In **managed workflow**, where you can see only `JavaScript`-related files, these files are generated in the `Expo` server = you have no access to these.

Answer (score -1):

React-native init  generates this. It's easiest to find and manipulate this through android studio. If it doesn't create it... the process failed somewhere.

Comment: Ok, but generates it where? How do you find it through android studio?